# How to extract information from a tiff through the use of a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, r, geotiff-tiff

I am having trouble in using the data from the South America amazon from a shapefile. What I was asked to do was to take the data from the loss of forest in a format where it is possible to make sense of it. But I am unable to pass the information to tif format, that I would use in Rstudio to make analysis with the temperature data that I have.

By my understanding a tif mask with the Amazonian deforestation is what i need, but I am open to other suggestions.

link to shapefile: http://www.imazongeo.org.br/downloads/imazon_sad_desmatamento_2017-01_amazonia.zip

ps: I have tried using QGIS to convert, but the dots are lost in the conversion, and I am unable to do it in R* too.

Comment: I understood that you want to convert the vector layer into a raster layer. I don't know R but with QGIS did you try the Processig Toolbox --> GRASS Modules -->  v.to.rast?

Comment: It seems you need very fine grids over a vast area. Probably you can divide the area into sub-regions, rasterize each of them, and then build VRT to cover whole area.